# Using DRF to update the whole of an object, including nested object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

If I have models that look roughly like this:-

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.PROTECT)


class Venue(models.Model):
    # all of this information comes from the Google Places API
    place_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.TextField()
```

and I want to be able to update the venue name of an existing event using Django Rest Framework, it looks like I have to write an update() method for my model serializer.

I've written it like this:-

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    venue = VenueSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ["title", "venue"]

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        venue_data = validated_data.pop("venue", None)

        event = super().update(instance, validated_data)

        if venue_data:
            venue, _ = Venue.objects.get_or_create(
                place_id=venue_data["place_id"],
                defaults={
                    "name": venue_data["name"],
                    "address": venue_data["address"]
                },
            )
            event.venue = venue
            event.save()

        return event
```

Does that look like I'm going in the right direction here? I don't want to create a new venue every time someone updates an event - if the place ID is the same as an existing one, I want to reuse it.

This code looks a bit cumbersome to me (I've got some very similar looking code in the create() method of the serializer) so I'm just worried that there's an easier, more concise way to go about this that I've somehow missed.

Comment: This code should not work as expected. `defaults` arg in `get_or_create` method will not update your `venue` `name` - it will be only used if new `Venue` is created. You should look at [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) method.

Comment: it doesn't a good way, you can update or partial update your Event but it does not make sense to update another model from a separate serializer, you can change venue of the even record but update the info of venue? no

Comment: @monio But I don't want to update the name or the address of the venue. I just want to be able to create a new venue (if requested).

Comment: @Nova I think that makes sense. So you're saying I should only update *which* venue the event is attached to, not the venue itself. But then, given that I want my users on the front end to be able to type the address of Google place into a search bar and then use the results to change the venue of the event, how should I allow that?